# How can I determine the page number of a table in MS Word Macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document in MS Word 2016 with 200+ pages and even more tables. I need to align all tables on odd pages to the left and I need all tables on even pages aligned to the right. Except for one or two tables which I can amend manually if needed none of the tables span multiple pages. Using

```
Dim oTable As Table
For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    oTable.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
Next oTable
```

I can align all tables to the right. When using `wdAlignParagraphLeft` instead of `wdAlignParagraphRight` I can align all tables to the left. But I could not figure our how to get the page number of a table so that I can assign the alignment based on the page number a table is on.

(The idea is that if printed as a book, the table are always on the inner side. If there is a better way to accomplish that I'll be listening. If printed as a book and two pages are next to each other the tables should be at the inner side like this:)

```
+-------------------------------+
|    Even Page  |   Odd page    |
+---------------+---------------+
|       |Table| | |Table|       |
|               |               |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yankee, You can determine the page number that a particular table sits on using:

```
oTable.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Therefor, to loop through all of the tables in your document and align them according to the odd or even nature of the page upon which they sit, you would use:

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim PageNo As Integer

For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    PageNo = oTable.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    If PageNo Mod 2 = 0 Then    'The page number is EVEN.
        oTable.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    Else                        'The page number is ODD.
        oTable.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    End If
Next oTable
```

Should you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: If a table has page breaks and you need to get a page where the table starts, you can call `tableRange.Collapse 1` before `tableRange.Information(...)`